# C++ using a "base" function inside an overload function

Tags: c++, overloading

while coding I came across a problem.

I use projective 2D-Space (i.e. 2D-points (x,y) and 3D-Points (x,y,w) ).
I also have a function taking in a projectiv point (3D).
For better reading and to avoid casting in the main I tried to write an overload for that function taking in the 2D-Point and calling the "base" function (simple example).
But the compiler does not compiles the code. There seems to be a link error (LNK 2001).

```
//"base" function
foo(3D_pt pt)
{
      //do something with it
}

//overloaded function
foo(2D_pt pt)
     3D_pt pt3 = 3D_pt(pt.x, pt.y, 1);
     foo(pt3);
}
```

Any ideas how to go about that?

Thanks

edit:
The error is:
LNK2001:
unresolved symbol - foo(2D_pt pt)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: LNK 2001 - unresolved external symbol.

Comment: @NewTech This is not enough, post the full error. Namely, what symbol is unresolved exactly.

Comment: @Paul: The compiler complains about the function not foo not know. The actual output is:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl CoordTransform::Car2Image(class cv::Point3_<float>,class CCamera<float>)" (?Car2Image@CoordTransform@@YA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@V?$Point3_@M@3@V?$CCamera@M@@@Z)

Comment: @NewTech please read the link  alexeykuzmin0 posted. The code you've given us does not produce the error message you've given us.

Comment: please note, that C++ identifiers may NOT start with a number. So `3D_pt` and `2D_pt` are invalid.

Comment: @NewTech Linker can't find definition for the function `class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl CoordTransform::Car2Image(class cv::Point3_<float>,class CCamera<float>)`, the error is not related to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem in the code posted are:

#1: Your class names (`2D_pt` and `3D_pt`) are starting with a number while an identifier in C++ should not do this ([Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)).

#2: The functions `foo` have no return type.

#3: `{` is missing in `foo(2D_pt)`.

After fixing, everything builds with no issues: [ideone](http://ideone.com/IXDxTt).

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be a different error than... I think a have to review my code.